# JavaScript Object Key not assignable, Field Is However

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

I am fairly new to JavaScript and I am wondering how I can take the value of a variable and set it as the key name to the corresponding field. I came across this when I was making a webapp, and what it does is take in signup data and puts it into a JS object to be sent to my API.

signup.html:

```
        <form id="signup-form" name ="signup-form">
            <input class="login-form-field" type="text" name="user" placeholder="username">
            <input class="login-form-field" type="text" name="email" placeholder="email">
            <input class="login-form-field" type="password" name="dob" placeholder="date of birth">
            <br>
            <!--<button class="actionButton"></button>-->
            <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" onClick="signupData(this.form)">
        </form>
```

Below you will see that when I use dob, it names the key dob and sets the field to the value of it. When I set the key to variable user it does not set the key to the value of variable user as I initially thought it would. How can I set the key to the value of variable user?

```
    function signupData(form) //add to this script
    {
      console.log("signup data is starting");
      var user = form.user.value;
      var email = form.email.value;
      var dob = form.dob.value;

      //genSKey();
     // genPKey();

      //var skey = getSKey();
      
    //var enUser = encryptMes(user);
    //var enEmail = encryptMes(email);
      //var endob = encryptMes(dob);

      var data = {name : "LifeNet", members : {user : {profilePic : {}, dob, listeners : {}, listening : {}, friends : {}, requested : {}, blocked : {}, channel: false}}}
      apiPost({data});
      //pass the signup function in here

      //hash the variables and send to celox network
      console.log(JSON.stringify({data}));
      //alert (`copy and save your Private Key to somewhere safe: ${skey}`);
    }
  </script>
```

Below you will see that it does not set the name to what I input in the signup form.
Browser:

```
{"data":{"name":"LifeNet","members":{"user":{"profilePic":{},"dob":"01/25/2000","listeners":{},"listening":{},"friends":{},"requested":{},"blocked":{},"channel":false}}}}
```

help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer as mentioned by Terry:

append to the existing object with bracket notation.

```
      var user = form.user.value;
      var email = form.email.value;
      var dob = form.dob.value;

     var data = {name:"LifeNet", members:{}};

    data.members[user] = {profilePic:{},dob, listeners:{}, listening:{}, friends:
{}, requested:{}, blocked:{}, channel:false}
```

Comment: You are not referencing the `user` variable anywhere in your object.

Comment: I think I may want to space out the object better, but if I am not mistaken I have it initialized and I am trying to use it as a key for another object in field for (user). ```var data = {name:"LifeNet", members:{user: etc... ```

Comment: If you want to use the string value of `user` as a key, you need to use bracket notation.

Comment: I will try that, thank you

Comment: What is your expected result, can you put up your expected result with dummy values?

Comment: yes, it worked thank you for your answer  ```var data = {name:"LifeNet", members:{}}

      data.members[user] = {profilePic:{},dob, listeners:{}, listening:{}, friends:{}, requested:{}, blocked:{}, channel:false}```

Comment: Browser output: ```{"data":{"name":"LifeNet","members":{"test":{"profilePic":{},"dob":"01/18/2000","listeners":{},"listening":{},"friends":{},"requested":{},"blocked":{},"channel":false}}}}```